# Написать программу дневник

Tags: python

Не могу понять как правильно реализовать эту задачу. Нужно написать программу дневник:

1. Спрашиваем у пользователя дату
2. Просим написать сообщение ( запись в дневник )
3. Создаём файл diary.txt
4. В него записывается всё записи + дата в таком формате:
   01.01.2020
   Привет, это первая запись
5. Записи дополняются и корректно отображается в файле со всеми отступами
   Условия: использовать функции и циклы.
   Я так понимаю, что мы сначала должны спросить у пользователя все данные  и занести их в файл. Только вот как это сделать нормально..  Я начал с этого:

   ```
    def diary_entry(date,message):
        file.write(date)
        file.write(message)
        file.close()

    word = True
    while word:
        date = input('Напишите дату :\n')
        date += '\n'
        message = input('Ваше сообщение :\n')
        message += '\n'
        file = open('files/diary.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        if date and message:
            diary_entry(date,message)
        else:
            print('Error')
   ```

В файл diary.txt ничего не появляется. Не могу понять в чем дело.
И еще вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы после того как пройдет первый цикл, в файле данные добавились а не перезаписались?

Answer (score 3):

Убрать int в строке

```
date = int(input('Напишите дату :\n'))
```

int() переводит в целое число. 12.12.20 целым числом не является.

Comment: спасибо, вот я накидал примерное решение теперь, но теперь не понимаю почему не записывает

Comment: @VladislavDudashvili потому что file, который вы открываете, и file в функции записи - разные вещи. Тут вам отдельная функция вообще не нужна.

Comment: так в задании нужно написать функцию.. Как тогда это реализовать?

Comment: Что значит "в задании нужно написать функцию"? Ну напишите der f(): pass. Ну или открывайте файл в функции тоже. А то получается, что душ включаете в ванной, а намыливать голову бежите на балкон :)

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю ответ, как сделать, чтобы данные не перезаписались, а добавились:

```py
Ваш_файл = open('имя_файла.txt', 'a')
# "a" добавляет в файл, а "w" перезаписывает
Ваш_файл.write('Какой-то текст')
# записываем данные в файл
Ваш_файл.close()
# закрываем файл, чтобы он не висел в памяти
```